# Tracking the activity life cycle

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I have requirement wherein I have to display a lock screen if the user moves out of the application.

Hence, the structure is: Activity A extends Activity B.
Wherein Activity B is the deciding activity : "was application in backgound". 
If so it launches the lock activity.

Now, say I am on activity A and receive a phone call. Hence the app gets into the background. 
When it resumes I can see the glimpse of Activity A for a fraction of second and then comes the lock activity.

Can there be any solution to avoid that glimpse of Activity A?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the lifecycle of activity from [**official doc**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

You are using activity B just to track whether activity is alive. I am not sure if it is necesary.

If activity goes to background `onPause()` method is called, it means activity is not visible (it might be both screen lock or home button pressed), and `onResume()` is called when activity is visible again. In Activity A if you override onPause method and launch your lock activity, it should work. (Or set a boolean onPause and launch lock activity on resume(you might see Activiy A though)

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Its not the only activity requiring the lock screen. there are n number of activities who want the lock screen and the ones not wanting it. So the activities who need the lock screen extend the Activity B